# UML Detecting usecase correctly

Tags: uml, use-case

[UML Diagrams](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case.html) says:

> A use case is a kind of behaviored classifier that specifies a
>   [complete] unit of [useful] functionality performed by [one or more]
>   subjects to which the use case applies in collaboration with one or
>   more actors, and which [for complete use cases] yields an observable
>   result that is of some value to those actors [or other stakeholders]
>   of each subject.

But it is not clear for me in specific small situation. For example in a mobile application I have a list and user can do

- ''item click'' for

  1. selecting item
  2. deselecting item
- ''long item click'' for
  changing selection mode (''multiple'' or ''single'')

Now, are usecases ''selecting item'', ''deselecting item'' and ''changing selection mode'' or they are ''item click'' and ''item ling click''?

I think ''item click'' and ''item long click'' are not UC because

1. Although ''item click'' and ''item long click'' are behaviors of list; but I did not create the application to provide a way for user to do  ''click'' and ''long click'' (those are not useful independently)
2. ''item click'' does not provide unit complete useful functionality (can lead to different useful behaviors with observable output: ''selecting/deselecting item'')

Am I right? I'm in doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The clicks are different behaviors (like different key strokes) you perform to achieve the goal of/trigger the underlying use case (`select item` etc.). Clicking something might be a use case if you are after some finger training. But you are probably dealing with some business goal to achieve.